# String cannot be converted to String[]

Tags: java

when i compile my program i receive this error:
String cannot be converted to String[]

my program is in 2 classes:

main:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class esa{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int [] numeri= new int[4];
        String [] text =new String[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        text[i] = args[i];
        System.out.println(text[i]);
        }
        text=est.conv(text);
    }
}


import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;


public class est{
public static String conv(String [] valori){

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's readable.  Use the **{}** button in the question editor.

Comment: My eyes! please fix your formatting

Comment: Indeed format your code, but also don't use wildcards in imports and a String is a single object while a String[] is an array of String. These things are not the same.

Comment: Down voting due to horribly formatted question. Normally when you ask for help you make things PRESENTABLE!

Answer (score 2):

```
text=est.conv(text);
```

`est` Class has a method `conv` which takes `String[]` and returns `String`.You cannot assign a `String` to `String[]`